# Starting Xcode Project From Scratch and cannot showing anything

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am following a book (Big Nerd Ranch IOS Programming) and the version of my xcode that I am using is slightly newer than the one that the book uses. As a consequence, I cannot exactly follow the books steps and one of those steps is to create a window-based application.

What I did was: I created an empty project which gives me the delegate and a few other files. I created my own MainWindow.xib.

I kept on reading and I am at the part where I need to compile and I am supposed to see something on the simulator. However, I do not see anything. I know that I am missing something here, because I am guessing that I have not wired up the MainWindow.xib correctly with the code (??). Note that the book told me to add map view, text field, and activity indicator to the main window.

I am wondering what is the proper way to get a project started from scratch. I actually prefer doing it this way so that I can get the lowdown of starting a ios project.

**UPDATE:**
After I set the Info.plist "Main nib file base name" to "MainWindow". I was able to see the view. However, I cannot click on the text field on the simulator and make the keyboard show up. I clicked the home button and when I tried clicking on the icon again, It would show white screen and not the map with text field over it.

**WhereamiAppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface WhereamiAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
    CLLocationManager * locationManager;
    IBOutlet MKMapView *worldView;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    IBOutlet UITextField *locationTitleField;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

**WhereamiAppDelegate.m**

```
#import "WhereamiAppDelegate.h"

@implementation WhereamiAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];    
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Could not find location: %@", error);
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"whereami" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"whereami.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

**main.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "WhereamiAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([WhereamiAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

[image: info.plist]

[image: MainWindow.xib]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953948/appdelegate-rootviewcontroller-and-uiapplication) (quoted from @WrightCS):

> MainWindow.xib is the defined in your info.plist as the Main nib file
>   base name. In your MainWindow.xib, you define the first controller
>   that you want to load, in your case, RootViewController.

Comment: i do not have a root view controller. do I use 'MainWindow' or 'MainWindow.xib' for the 'Main nib file base name'. The file's owner in this case will jsut be my delegate.

Comment: I set the 'Main nib file base name' in the info.plist to "MainWindow" and it's showing !

Comment: Then mark this answer as the solution (click the checkmark left to it).

Comment: That's an entirely different issue and thus should be asked in a separate question. In addition, the stuff you are trying to do (outlets for views etc.) should be implemented in a view controller and NOT the application delegate!

Answer (score 1):

Check your `main.m` file (assuming you have one - if not, that's part of your problem). You'll probably see a line like this:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

For your app to do anything, it should be something like this:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"UIApplication", @"MyAppDelegate");
```

Assuming you have `MyAppDelegate.h` and `MyAppDelegate.m` in your project.

Comment: This is what I have "return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([WhereamiAppDelegate class]));"

Comment: Actually, it is because my main nib. I was able to configure it by setting the main nib to "MainWindow"